# Websocket on port 443 with SSL works only for some pages

Tags: html, proxy, websocket, firewall

i experienced that a customer successfully executed the websocket test for page 443 (with SSL) on http://websocketstest.com/. But when he tries to connect to our page with websockets on port 443 with SSL it does't work.

The differences between both are the following:
 - we use binary websocket connection, websockettest.com not
 - our origin in from https, websockettest.com not.

Does someone know if a proxy or firewall may block websocket connections due to this differences.

BTW we are using plaing javascript ws api to connect to our backend (which is a nginx as proxy for our jetty)

Thx in advance